# Multiupload file field with additional fields solution in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, multi-upload

I am looking for a solution which would allow me to upload multiple files at once, but these files has additional fields attached to them. Imagine music album creation - I need to upload multiple mp3 files, each with title, duration, author name, etc... I have been messing around with multiupload widgets, but these do not allow to have additional fields. Regarding the field - I have been trying field_collection as well as entity inline field, but I could not get the field to work with either of them. There is even some patch for multiupload file widget which should allow me to upload entity inline fields, but it does not seem to work (no additional fields after upload). I am lost now.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [file Entity module](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) makes files in Drupal entities. Entities in Drupal are fieldable, which means you can attach fields ( title, duration, author name, etc) to files (images, videos, audios, documents, etc).

From the project page:"File entity provides interfaces for managing files. It also extends the core file entity, allowing files to be fieldable..."

[Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) Provides integration between for the Plupload widget to upload multiple files and Drupal.

In combination with other modules like Media or [Bulk Media Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/bulk_media_upload) and the Editable Fields module, you can mass  edit the fields for each of the media nodes.